# Wordpress admin for a custom post, hide/collapse the main "title" and "description" boxes

Tags: custom-post-types, admin

Is there a way to hide the main "title" and "description" boxes for a custom post?

I have a custom post with a large meta box. I won't be using the regular title and description so I would like to either hide it or collapse it so the user won't have to scroll to get down to my meta box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you register the CPT, you register it with `supports`. If you do not include `title` and `editor` in this array wordpress will not display the main title or the TinyMCE editor.